# How can I check if a user has grabbed a scrollbar on a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Basically I want to see if a user has a hold of a scrollbar on my site. is there a Jquery function I can use to return a Boolean based on weather the user has a hold of the scrollbar or not?

Edit: adding my site so you can see the problem. When you try to scroll the scrollbar up the timed event to set the scrollbar to the bottom kicks in and sends it to the bottom. I need it to not do that while focus is on the chatbox/chatbox scrollbar, but it's not working: http://exvs.us/

Comment: Grabbed it and moved it or just grabbed it?

Comment: just grabbed. so like I can say "move the scroll bar to the bottom/top unless the user has ahold of it" cause I don't want to interrupt them if they're reading something.

Comment: WTB Code paying with Solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to accomplish this, one way would be to hide the default scrollbar and create your own in javascript.  You can then handle click events on your scrollbar.  However, this won't work well for users that have javascript disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Use scroll method of the Jquery object :

more information there => http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

sample :

```
$(window).scroll( function () {

  console.log('pretty easy no ?');

});
```

Comment: sorry, this doesn't help. I added more information on the first post though

Comment: @CyanPrime you can't know if the scrollbar is grabbed or not, the best is the way Bill has defined but this is really not reliable, and actually i don't see why you would want to add an event on grabbing, the user might know in what purpose he grabs the bar, you should try to minimize such interactions, it could make the user be overwhelmed as well.